# Validation Summary in WPF using IDataErrorInfo and Validation.Errors

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, validation, data-binding

I have a ViewModel with an ObservableCollection of objects that implement IDataErrorInfo:

```
public class ActivityCodesEditorViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<UIActivityCode> ActivityCodes
}
public class UIActivityCode : IActivityCode, INotifyPropertyChanged, IDataErrorInfo
```

This collection is bound to a datagrid (an infragistics XamDataGrid, but I think that's irrelevant).  The validation works great on the cell level, showing which objects have validation errors.

Now, I want to not only show the errors inline, but also provide something similar to a ValidationSummary that we have in asp.net.  I've seen solutions online, all of which use a private hashset to keep track of errors.  I don't want that overhead, and I think it's already being taken care of by the framework via Validation.Errors.

My UI looks something like this:

```
<ListBox ItemSource="{Binding ElementName=ActivityCodesGrid, Path=(Validation.Errors)}" />
<igDP:XamDataGrid Name="ActivityCodesGrid"  DataSource="{Binding ActivityCodes}" />
```

You see, I want to bind the Validation.Errors property to something that will display them, but I'm having trouble either binding to them correctly or getting updated versions of it.  **Is this possible to bind directly to Validation.Errors like this**?

**EDIT 1**

Blast!  Once I posted this question, I found this:

[Listing all Validation.Errors in a single WPF control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615631/listing-all-validation-errors-in-a-single-wpf-control?rq=1)

It seems Validation.Errors is misleading by being an array.  I'm going to try the solution listed in the second answer.  If you have something different than the linked answers offer, please share!

Comment: Did you find an acceptable solution?