# Dynamically change control property based on other controls

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

In WPF, I have a grid with one row and two columns.

```
<Grid>
 <Textbox Grid.Column=0>
  <Validation.ErrorTemplate>
   <DockPanel>
    <Image DockPanel.Dock="Right" Margin="20,0,0,0"/>
   </DockPanel>
  </Validation.ErrorTemplate>
 </Textbox>
<Button Grid.Column=1>
</Button>
```

I want the image (error icon) to stay on the right of the button, which can have a variable size depending on its text.  Is there a way to dynamically set the margin of the image based on width of the button? Right now it is just fixed to 20 pixels to the right of the textbox.

Comment: you mean you want the error icon to appear right to the text box not the button !!

Comment: @Sniffer, I want the error icon placed relative to the button, not the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

Validation Error template is shown in a special adorner layer.
If you need position you elements relative to adorned element just use [AdornedElementPlaceholder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.adornedelementplaceholder.aspx) class in you XAML.

Comment: I can add the AdornedElementPlaceholder to the Textbox, but that just defines its position relative to the textbox. But I want it relative to the button control...

Comment: Then ou can try to offset position of the adorner with the margins applied to AdornedElementPlaceholder. And these margins can be bound to button's actual height/width. But this is quite fragile

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to accomplish what you are trying to, see you can't reference an element from within a data template unless the referenced element is defined inside that template or style. You can do it in another way, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615631/listing-all-validation-errors-in-a-single-wpf-control).